# White screen after Splash Screen react-native

Tags: android, react-native

[EDIT] Seems to be that the white screen is generate because MainActivity is to heavy to load, i managed to solve using first a native splash screen and then right after native is killed a js implementation based on the next plugin, i did some modifications to match both splash screens perfectly
https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen

White screen after splash screen react native.

[image]

splash_screen.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@color/gray"/>
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

styles.xml

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
    <style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

AndroidManifiest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.appba"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

SplashActivity.java

```
package com.appba;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.appba;

import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {
    /**
     * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript.
     * This is used to schedule rendering of the component.
     */
    @Override
    protected String getMainComponentName() {
        return "appBa";
    }
}
```

Any idea how to avoid that blank screen?,

I couldn't find a solution on google

My splash is based on the following approach.
https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/

Comment: From my understanding, the above method works on that time lag for loading of the Main Activity, where the theme is splash screen until the Main theme is loaded. It works pretty well for me, with smooth transition all the way. Maybe provide the style and Main code along with a gif showing what's actually happening in your app?

Comment: yes, edidted with more info, can you cheack now please

Comment: @Mars Did you find any solution. Having same problem here

Answer (score 1):

Firstly load your LauncherActivity as  MainActivity

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent i = new Intent(this, Splash.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Splash.java

```
private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 5000;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            finish();
        }
    }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
}
```

Comment: The line  `setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);` makes my app build fail. I removed it and my app loaded fine once, but then kept crashing.

Answer (score 0):

if your activity show data from database It is normal to Freezes (White Screen ) for a while ,If that is what you want you should use `ProgressDialog` or `ProgressBar` inside `AsyncTask`

Comment: @Mars try to add this lines in your MANIFAST .xml 
`<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>`

inside activity main 

`<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity" 
........ 
`

Comment: but that goes on SplashActivity right? because that is the entry point and then call MainActivity from SplashActivity

Answer (score 0):

I know two ways for solve this problem.
1. Write code on java for making more big delay on Splash screen.
2. Add android:theme="@style/AppTheme" in activity .MainActivity (in this case user doesn't have time to see difference between splash and MainActivity activites).

Comment: that is not a solution, the only way that i found is show first the native splash screen and then show a js based with the same background

Comment: I did splash and js file with same background but still i can see white screen in between. after native splash and before js splash. how did u fix your issue?